# Server with multiple IP addresses?

Tags: linux, centos, ip, python

just wondering how it is actually possible to have a server with multiple IPs

---

I have a python script, and would like to be able to use different IP addresses for different requests.

Is this actually possible?

---

**EDIT:**

I'm running CentOS 5 and have 3 IP Addresses asscociated with the machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this a question about Python (a) or having multiple IPs on the server (b)?

If (a) then yes, you just have to bind the socket to a particular IP address that you want to use. For example:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(YOUR_IP_ADDRESS)
s.connect((REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT))
```

Anticipating a question about the urlopen, pls look at my comment on StackOverflow

If (b) then you just configure additional IPs in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:X` /where X is a virtual interface ID, 0, 1, 2, etc) (assuming that all IPs are on that interface. If they are not then provision them in ifcfg-eth1, etc)

Once the configuration is in place, restart your network: `service network restart`

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Run **ifconfig** on the server and it will show you all the network attachments on the server and their currently bound IP addresses.

To add an additional IP to one of the network adapters, edit it into the network configuration file for that adapter. The files are explained here: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-files.html